# How to remove the empty rows created due to jsf h:panelgrid?

Tags: panelgrid

I am using h:datatable to display dynamic table. The rows have to displayed based on some condition. I am using h:panelgrid with rendered condition but in case the condition is not satisfied it simply shows empty rows. How to get rid of those empty rows ??

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/559622/JSF/java/panelGrid-empty-space-cells